# Is it correct behaviour to use Facebook and Google simply as an obstacle to get into my app?

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin

I'm implementing Facebook Login and Google Sign In in a "Sign In" activity.  Once the user successfully logs in and I get their email they can escape the "Sign In" activity and enter the app.  When the user "logs out" I delete their email and they are pushed out to the "Sign In" activity again.

Is it correct behaviour to use Facebook and Google simply as an obstacle to get into my app?  Once I get their email (and possibly token) I can determine if they are signed in or not myself?

I found it really impractical trying to get google and/or facebook handle the login state.

Comment: It is rather common, many apps use it as a simple way to offload the authentication and account creation burden to bigger parties, but it's not always appreciated. Depending on your audience, it will cause some people to uninstall your app right away.  

A good compromise is usually to offer all three (Google, Facebook, manual Email) to users.

Comment: Great thanks!  Yeah I have never seen an app without the manual option.  With the manual option I guess I have to transmit their username to the server?  With the others I can send the token to the server and retrieve their username with it.

Comment: It's more work than that. You'll want to send verification emails, to prevent people logging in with random addresses, which does require to store their email on your server, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not allow the user to use their email address to sign in? Not everyone uses Facebook and not everyone wants to give access to their Google account. If you aren't worried about either of these scenarios, then go for it. But if you are and you want a larger user base, allow an alternative.

Comment: It is much easier for the user to press a button instead of entering their email and choosing a password and then remembering that password.  Besides, whether or not I add that option as well is irrelevant to my question.